# Doing platform specific things in gdbinit

Tags: gdb

I develop on both mac and linux and have one network mounted home directory that is shared between them.  On linux, it is useful to have the following in my .gdbinit:

```
set print thread-events off
```

Unfortunately, this errors on mac:

```
(gdb) set print thread-events off
Undefined set print command: "thread-events off".  Try "help set print".
```

Is there a way in .gdbinit to have this command only executed on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `~/.gdbinit.Linux` and `~/.gdbinit.MacOS`, then (bash syntax):

```
alias gdb="gdb -ex \"source ~/.gdbinit.$(uname)\""
```

Of course you could do the same thing with a gdb shell wrapper script instead of an alias.

Alternatively you can build `GDB` 7.x on both, and have full power of `Python` at your disposal.